# how to withdraw L2 funds from polygon?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have a question about gnosis safe, specifically reclaiming funds sent to the safe's address on polygon (chain 137) on a v1.1.1 safe created with this txn on the mainnet: a
I have a question about gnosis safe, specifically reclaiming funds sent to the safe's address on polygon (chain 137) on a v1.1.1 safe created with this txn on the mainnet: 0x296fe57c2c227b7b37c3901844607e22633d2c12c98f8430727bfbed56d27de2

what can i do to deploy a safe at address 0xde21f729137c5af1b01d73af1dc21effa2b8a0d6 on polygon, and claim the $15k in funds there?

i'm following the guide here ( https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741 ) about how to deploy this safe on polygon, and was able to generate a safe via txn https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x39b51d747f9cd7815c62fa9417264f809d9ffad084ad3ebadedfc818fa3191be on polygon, but the address of the generated safe is address ( 0x4f3000b30193baff8a4b80eba191139a63e2cc88 ) - not the same as the address generated on the mainnet ( 0xde21f729137c5af1b01d73af1dc21effa2b8a0d6 ).

one thing i was thinking about doing was incrementing the nonce on my deployed address ( 0x00de4b13153673bcae2616b67bf822500d325fc3 ) on polygon, which is currently 15, to 4062 (which was the nonce on my original mainnet deploy tx).  would that work?  or is the nonce of the deployer account non-material and its the proxy that matters?

thanks in advance.
what can i do to deploy a safe at address 0xde21f729137c5af1b01d73af1dc21effa2b8a0d6 on polygon, and claim the $15k in funds there?
i'm following the guide here ( https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741 ) about how to deploy this safe on polygon, and was able to generate a safe via txn https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x39b51d747f9cd7815c62fa9417264f809d9ffad084ad3ebadedfc818fa3191be on polygon, but the address of the generated safe is address ( 0x4f3000b30193baff8a4b80eba191139a63e2cc88 ) - not the same as the address generated on the mainnet ( 0xde21f729137c5af1b01d73af1dc21effa2b8a0d6 ).
one thing i was thinking about doing was incrementing the nonce on my deployed address ( 0x00de4b13153673bcae2616b67bf822500d325fc3 ) on polygon, which is currently 15, to 4062 (which was the nonce on my original mainnet deploy tx). would that work? or is the nonce of the deployer account non-material and its the proxy that matters?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some general context can be found here https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5267779-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover.

In your case the Safe was created using `createProxy` which relies on the `create` opcode to deploy a new contract. The address of the new contract is based on the address of the contracts using `create` and its nonce. In our context this is the GnosisSafeProxyFactory. Therefore it is important that the nonce of that factory is the same as when you created your original Safe. (Meaning increasing the nonce of your EOA will not change anything).

I didn't query the nonce on polygon, but looking at [polygonscan](https://polygonscan.com/txsInternal?a=0x76e2cfc1f5fa8f6a5b3fc4c8f4788f0116861f9b) we can see more than 10k internal transactions, therefore the nonce is likely higher than this.

On mainnet the nonce of the factory at the point of creation of your Safe was 3302 according to [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x296fe57c2c227b7b37c3901844607e22633d2c12c98f8430727bfbed56d27de2#statechange). Therefore it will not be possible to recreate a contract at the same address anymore.